# Convergence of an iterated double sum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, summation

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. I want to show that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n + m}}{n! m!} \left( \frac{(k + n + m)!}{k!}\right)^\frac{1}{2} \right) < \infty \ .$$
I have specifically put the parantheses on the inner sum because I think the order of summation is important in this problem.

I have so far been attempting to separate the $n$ and $m$ in a suitable way. In particular, I have tried the following
$$ \left( \frac{(k + n + m)!}{k!}\right)^\frac{1}{2}  = \prod_{i=1}^{n+m} (k + i )^\frac{1}{2} = e^{\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n+m} \ln(k + i)} \ .$$
Now, we use the estimate
$$ \ln(k + i) - \ln(k) \leq \frac{i}{k} \ .$$
Applying this, we have
$$e^{\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n+m} \ln(k + i)} = e^{\frac{n + m - 1}{2} \ln p} e^{\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n+m} \ln(k + i) - \ln(k)} \leq e^{\frac{n + m - 1}{2} \ln p} e^{\frac{1}{2 k} \sum_{i=1}^{n+m} i} = e^{\frac{n + m - 1}{2} \ln p} e^{\frac{(n+m + 1) (n + m)}{4p}} \ .$$
However, I am unable to properly make use of this bound. The problem with this series seems to be that I need to be able to first evaluate the sum over the index $m$ to something tractable which has to be summed over $n$.

Answer (score 1):

First assume that $n,m,x,k \geq 0$ , So

$\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum \limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+m}}{n! m!} (\frac{(n+m+k)!}{k!})^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Now $(\frac{(n+m+k)!}{k!})^{\frac{1}{2}} = \prod \limits_{i=1}^{n+m} (k+i)^{\frac{1}{2}} = e^{\frac{1}{2}\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n+m} \ln(k+i)}$

$\ln(k+i)-\ln(i) \leq \frac{k}{i}$ => $\ln(1+\frac{k}{i}) \leq \frac{k}{i}$ , exponent-ate both side to get $1+\frac{k}{i} \leq 1+\frac{k}{i}+\frac{k^2}{2i^2}+\cdots$

=> $e^{\frac{1}{2}\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n+m} \ln(i)+\frac{k}{i}} = e^{\frac{1}{2}(k H_{n+m}+\ln((n+m)!))}$

Where $H_x$ is the harmonic series and $H_x \leq \ln x +1$, so

=> $k H_{n+m}+\ln((n+m)!)= k+k\ln(n+m) +ln((n+m)!)$

So $e^{\frac{1}{2}\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n+m} \ln(k+i)} \leq e^{\frac{1}{2}k +\frac{1}{2}k \ln(m+n) + \frac{1}{2}\ln((n+m)!)}= e^{\frac{k}{2}} * (m+n)^{\frac{k}{2}} *\sqrt{(m+n)!} $

So its all becomes, $e^{\frac{k}{2}} \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum \limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+m}  (n+m)^{\frac{k}{2}} \sqrt{(n+m)!}}{n! m!}$,

From here i will be using Stirling's bound for the factorial function(things will start to be messy before they become pretty).

$\sqrt{2\pi} x^x e^{-x} \sqrt{x} < x! < e x^x e^{-x} \sqrt{x} $ (and remember we are trying to maximize the expression so factorials in the numerator gets the upper bound while factorials in the denominator gets the lower bound).

it becomes $e^{\frac{k}{2}} \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum \limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+m}  (n+m)^{\frac{k}{2}} \sqrt{e (n+m)^{n+m} *e^{-n-m} \sqrt{n+m}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi} n^n e^{-n} \sqrt{n} \sqrt{2\pi} m^m e^{-m} \sqrt{m}}$

=> $e^{\frac{k}{2}} \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum \limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+m} (n+m)^{\frac{k}{2}} \sqrt{e} (n+m)^{\frac{n+m}{2}} e^{-\frac{n+m}{2}} \sqrt[4]{n+m}}{2 \pi n^n m^m e^{-n-m} \sqrt{n m}}$

=> $\frac{e^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{2 \pi} \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum \limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+m} (n+m)^{\frac{k}{2}} (n+m)^{\frac{n+m}{2}} e^{-\frac{n+m}{2}}}{n^n m^m e^{-n-m}}$ (and i removed the fraction $\frac{\sqrt[4]{n+m}}{\sqrt{n m}}$ since its less than $1$ when $n,m \geq 2$, and we want to maximize).

=> $\frac{e^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{2 \pi} \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum \limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+m} (n+m)^{\frac{k}{2}} (n+m)^{\frac{n+m}{2}} e^{\frac{n+m}{2}}}{n^n m^m }$

Applying HM-GM inequality for $n^n m^m$ we get that $n^n m^m \geq (\frac{m+n}{2})^{m+n}$, so we get that

=> $\frac{e^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{2 \pi} \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum \limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+m} (n+m)^{\frac{k}{2}} (n+m)^{\frac{n+m}{2}} e^{\frac{n+m}{2}}}{(\frac{m+n}{2})^{m+n}}$

=> $\frac{e^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{2 \pi} \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum \limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+m} (n+m)^{\frac{k}{2}} (n+m)^{\frac{n+m}{2}} e^{\frac{n+m}{2}}}{(\frac{m+n}{2})^{m+n}} \frac{2^{m+n}}{2^{m+n}}$

=> $\frac{e^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{2 \pi} \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum \limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+m} (n+m)^{\frac{k}{2}} (n+m)^{\frac{n+m}{2}} e^{\frac{n+m}{2}} 2^{m+n}}{(m+n)^{m+n}}$

=> $\frac{e^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{2 \pi} \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum \limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+m} (n+m)^{\frac{k}{2}}  e^{\frac{n+m}{2}} 2^{m+n}}{(m+n)^{\frac{m+n}{2}}}$

=> $\frac{e^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{2 \pi} \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum \limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x^2)^{\frac{n+m}{2}} (n+m)^{\frac{k}{2}}  e^{\frac{n+m}{2}} 4^{\frac{m+n}{2}}}{(m+n)^{\frac{m+n}{2}}}$

=> $\frac{e^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{2 \pi} \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum \limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x^2)^{\frac{n+m}{2}} (n+m)^{\frac{k}{2}}  e^{\frac{n+m}{2}} 4^{\frac{m+n}{2}}}{(\sqrt{m+n})^{\frac{m+n}{2}} (\sqrt{m+n})^{\frac{m+n}{2}}}$

=> $\frac{e^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{2 \pi} \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum \limits_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(4 e x^2)^{\frac{n+m}{2}} (n+m)^{\frac{k}{2}}}{(\sqrt{m+n})^{\frac{m+n}{2}} (\sqrt{m+n})^{\frac{m+n}{2}}}$

so when is $4e x^2 < \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n+m}$ and its when $n+m > 64 e^2 x^4$,

and to maximize it from there we will deal with it as $(\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{n+m}{2}}$.

so we arrive at ,

=> $\frac{e^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{2 \pi} \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum \limits_{m=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{n+m}{2}} \frac{(n+m)^{\frac{k}{2}}}{ (\sqrt{m+n})^{\frac{m+n}{2}}}$

=> $\frac{e^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{2 \pi} \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum \limits_{m=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{n+m}{2}} \frac{(\sqrt{n+m})^{k}}{ (\sqrt{m+n})^{\frac{n+m}{2}}}$

so when $\frac{n+m}{2} \geq k$ we will have that $ \frac{(\sqrt{n+m})^{k}}{ (\sqrt{m+n})^{\frac{n+m}{2}}}$ less than $1$ and to maximize we remove it.

this is true when $n+m >2k$, so when $n+m >2k+64e^2 x^4$ we have the maximized summation which is

=> $\frac{e^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{2 \pi} \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum \limits_{m=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{n+m}{2}} = \frac{\left(3+2 \sqrt{2}\right) e^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{\pi }$ which is a finite value, and since the number of integer $n,m$ such that $n+m \leq 2k+64 e^2 x^4$ is also finite ,so if we sum finite value finite number of times its clearly that its $< \infty$.

Thus concluding the proof.